# React Native- Set the height of View same as the content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a parent `View` container that has two children `Views` with `flexDirection: row`

The height of one child `View` is more than the height of another `child` View because of the content it has.

What I want to do?

I want to place a vertically centered text in one of the child views that is shorter in height. In the below example, the text 'BUDGET' should be at the center of the image which is next to it.

Here, is the snack link to my problem.

https://snack.expo.io/ByWT6Cb5V

But the problem is if I do `alignSelf: center`, react native is considering the height of the bigger child View and is centering the text according to that context

**P.S** `marginTop` does the Job for me, but I feel like, its kind of a work around.

**My real question is,** why the height of the View which has less contents taking up the same height as that of its sibling View?

Answer (score 0):

actually i don't understand your question whish you say (( In the below example, the text 'BUDGET' should be at the center to the image which is next to it.)) if you want show some thing inside an image, for example as you say show 'BUDGET' in the center part of that you should use image background:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image,ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
//import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
// import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:100}}>
            <View style={styles.budgetBlock}>
                            <View style={styles.budgetTextBlock}>
                                <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} style={{width:50, height:50,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}} >
                                <Text style={styles.budgetText}> BUDGET </Text>
</ImageBackground>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.budgetValueBlock}>
                                    <Text style={styles.budgetType}> Too High </Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.budgetType}> Too High</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.budgetType}> Too High</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.budgetType}> Too High</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but if you doesn't meant it and your purpose of "be at the center" is vertical align. you should do it:

```
 budgetTextBlock: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',<<<<<<this shows BUDGET in center
    height: 'auto',

}
```

Comment: This won't work, that's what I said in the question

Comment: I did test second one right on your online snack.expo and the budget place came to center ....

Comment: Came to the center of the image? Can you please save the snack and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

use `flex:1` in the child component wrapper e.g

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>...</View>
```